# Printing 2 dimension list by row and column

Tags: python-3.x

Print the 2-dimensional list mult_table by row and column. Using nested loops. Sample output for the given program(without spacing between each row):

1 | 2 | 3

2 | 4 | 6

3 | 6 | 9

This is my code: I tried using a nested loop but I have my output at the bottom. It has the extra | at the end

```
  for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row:
       print(cell,end=' | ' )
  print()
```

1 | 2 | 3 |

2 | 4 | 6 |

3 | 6 | 9 |

Comment: "|".join( [str(cell) for cell in row ] )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
for row in mult_table:
    print(" | ".join([str(cell) for cell in row]))
```

The `join()` joins the given elements into one string, using `" | "` as the separator.  So for three in a `row`, it only uses two separators.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for x in mult_table:
        for x1 in x:
            if x1 == x[-1]:
                print (x1)
            else:
                print(x1 , end=' | ')
```

Comment: While this code may give the OP the answer they are seeking, it is better to add context.  Explain why your solution works, or what to pay attention to in your solution.  To be a "quality" answer, future visitors should be able to learn from your post, so they can apply it to their own solutions.  For example, maybe explain what `x[-1]` does., and why that is the key to your solution. Full, quality answers with good explanations are more likely to be upvoted, and keeps SO quality high.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# To convert the input string into a two-dimensional list.
# Ex: 1 2, 2 4 is converted to [ [1, 2], [2, 4] ]
mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row in mult_table:
   i=0
   for num in row:
     if i<len(row)-1:
        print(row[i],end=' | ')
        i=i+1
     else:
        print(row[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
user_input= input()
lines = user_input.`enter code here`split(',')

# This line uses a construct called a list comprehension, introduced elsewhere,
# to convert the input string into a two-dimensional list.
# Ex: 1 2, 2 4 is converted to [ [1, 2], [2, 4] ]

mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row:
        if cell == row[len(row) - 1]:
            print(cell, end='')
        else:
            print(cell, end=' | ')
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

I know my answer is a little long, but it works.

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

''' Your solution goes here '''
if len(mult_table) <= 3:
    mult_table[0].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[0].insert(3, ' | ')
    
    mult_table[1].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[1].insert(3, ' | ')

    mult_table[2].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[2].insert(3, ' | ')
    
else:
    mult_table[0].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[0].insert(3, ' | ')
    mult_table[0].insert(5, ' | ')
    
    mult_table[1].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[1].insert(3, ' | ')
    mult_table[1].insert(5, ' | ')

    mult_table[2].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[2].insert(3, ' | ')
    mult_table[2].insert(5, ' | ')
    
    mult_table[3].insert(1, ' | ')
    mult_table[3].insert(3, ' | ')
    mult_table[3].insert(5, ' | ')
    
for x in mult_table:
    for y in x:
        print(y, end='')
    print()
```